# How to use Java API to parse xml string with XSLT and generate output in memory only?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xslt

I need to parse the internal XML(from a response) with predefined XSLT and send back the parsed result in html to the client. I notice the following example to use and generate local files. How to avoid the file creation with Java API? I want to replace the source.xml with String and generate the html output on the fly.

```
  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer (new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource("searchresult.xslt"));
   transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource("source.xml"),
           new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult( new FileOutputStream("result.html")));
```

Comment: to StreamResult use StringWriter instead of FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

StreamSource has [a constructor taking a Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.io.Reader%29) as argument. You can thus pass a StringReader, which will read the XML from a String, as argument.

Similarly, [the StreamResult constructor the example uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult%28java.io.OutputStream%29) takes an OutputStream as argument. You can thus pass any kind of OutputStream (like the HTTP response output stream, or a ByteArrayOutputStream, or a socket output stream) to send the result to wherever you like.